# Add result subquery in field the query Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables and I need to list all records from table A and create a field 'images' that receives the subquery from table B with a join to retrieve from table B only the images that match the ID of table A.

> Using Laravel 8

UserController.php

```
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $users = User::where('active', 1)
    ->leftJoin('images', 'users.id','=','id_user')
    ->paginate(10);
    return UserResource::collection($users);
}
```

Is not working

```
Table A (Users)
id  | name  | active
1   | John  | 1
2   | Mary  | 1

Table B (Images)
id  | image         | id_user
1   | 123.png       | 1
2   | 222.png       | 1
3   | 333.png       | 1
4   | 565.png       | 2


I need to do:

[
   {
      id:1,
      name: John, 
      images: [
         "123.png",
         "222.png",
         "333.png"
      ]
   },
   {
      id:2,
      name: Mary, 
      images: [
         "565.png"
      ] 
   }        
]
```

Comment: What does "*Is not working*" mean?  Have you tried specifying the `id_user` column with the table name, [as the docs and all examples I can fine here on SO show to do](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#left-join-right-join-clause)?  `->leftJoin('images', 'users.id', '=', 'images.id_user')`?

Comment: PS - this looks like a standard 1-to-many relationship, is there a reason you are no using Laravel relationships?  They make this kind of thing so much simpler :-)

Comment: @Don'tPanic, I couldn't get it to work with ->paginate(15) only one register